# I can't print an AutoCAD document with the original size

Tags: file-size, scale, autocad

When I try to print an AutoCAD design on A4 paper, it doesn't get like the original size, for example my design 13×23 when I print it is like this:

[image]

I hope someone experienced will answer my question.

Comment: I know nothing about AutoCAD. But I'm wondering why you show us the print dialogue? Does that mean that we should be able to see something is wrong? Is your design that tiny rectangle on the middle of the A4 in the preview? You say that your design is 13x23.  What's the unit? Under plot scale it says that 1 unit = 1 mm. So it seems like you're telling the program to print your design at 13x23 mm size.

Comment: yeah my design is this tiny rectangle and the unit is mm

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: sorry I mean cm

Comment: I don't know what I'm talking about, but can't you just choose cm instead of mm then?

Comment: unfortunately  no

Comment: This is progressing very slowly . *Why* can't you choose cm? Isn't it available in the drop-down? Then how about setting *unit* to 0.1?

Comment: yeah really slow haha but yes it's not available there are just inches and mm  . u know basically  1:1 work but I don't know why it doesn't with me ..

Comment: But what do you say to my suggestion to set *unit* to 0.1? If `0.1 unit = 1 mm` then `1 unit = 10 mm = 1 cm`.

Comment: Thank u for the heads up , this sound good way I'll try it soon 

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure about the nomenclature you are using but, it looks like your design is 13mm x 23mm and it shows in the print dialog that you are not scaling it up to fit a paper that is 210mm x 297 mm (it shows the scale at 1:1).

Try either clicking on the drop down next to where it says "scale" to scale the design up or check the box next to where it says "Fit to Paper" and see if that helps.

Comment: I remember that I reply to u! , but anyway I tried this and didn't work ...